# Best Practice in Firestore (or maybe NoSQL in general)

Tags: sql, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, relational-database

I really need some opinions from NoSQL experts, because I mainly was on the relational database train the last few years.

I am going to develop an app where users can track something on a daily basis and I really don't know what could be the best way to store the data. The app is going to be developed with Flutter, so I used Firestore as a database because of the reason that both are published by Google.

The problem I have is the following:

- There are going to be three pages where the data is needed:

  1. A Detail Page with additional information about the tracked data
  2. A daily overview to display the average, minimum and maximum of the data
  3. A weekly overview to display the average over the week

If this was a SQL scenario, I would just enter the data in the table for the detail page and display the rest of the data based on views I would create - meaning I only have to update the detailed table.

But in Firestore (or NoSQL, json format) everything's a document, right?
I watched [this video about how to structure one's data in Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo&t=1s) but it only made me realize that it's not that **simple**.

According to that video, a good practice seems to be creating a document for each page, but this would mean that in my case I need a document for Detail Page, Daily Overview, Weekly Overview because Firestore does not allow partial document reads. And everytime a new document or update happens in the Detail Page, 2 additional writes for an update are necessary in the other two documents - whichs seems highly error-prone to me. Also, Google start's billing Firestore Projects based on the amount of reads and writes.

So in short: Should I use a relational database instead or just don't use firestore and switch to another JSON type database?

I am sorry if this question may be too vague or a phylosophical topic but I really need some expert opinions.

Comment: Apparently the question is more concerned about pricing, for me it is cheaper if you use a different database but in terms of features I recommend the Firestore.

Comment: pricing is not my concern. I am more concerned about how it will not fit for my use case. I don't really understand why I should create a document for every different use case/page and need to keep in mind to update my aggregated values every time in the host site when all I want is to write the data once in a document and use it foe further aggregation and statistics.